# File shares from a DMZ into an internal network

Tags: firewalls, access-control, file-upload

We have a firewall policy that prohibits MS RPC through firewall, particularly from internet facing DMZ's back to the internal network. There is a business unit requesting an alternative method to transfer their files to the internal network to make files available to users on the internal network.

Anyone have any good ideas around this?  Systems like SFTP seem a bit cumbersome for this, so I'm looking for any alternative that would make life easy for the users and the system owners while still meeting the no RPC requirement.

Comment: If the files would be coming from outside, why not VPN?

Comment: What's your problem with SFTP?

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with SFTP? You can [mount it as a drive](https://superuser.com/questions/55860/sftp-as-a-folder-on-vista) if WinSCP isn't enough and they really must have it look like a Windows folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try a web based solution that you can manage from inside of your organization and users with rights can generate upload links. A commercial solution that does this is called Accellion. You might find opensource apps that can do this for you as well.